# Using Google Tasks API in Google Apps Script - Access not Configured

Tags: google-apps-script, google-tasks-api

I am getting 'Access not configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project' message.

I followed the guidance in the Google Developers Console documentation. I selected the 'Advanced Google Services' submenu under 'Resources' menu. I turned on the Google Tasks API and copied the API key from the Developers Console and pasted it into the 'Advanced Google Services' dialog and clicked OK.

I typed the example code from 'List task list' on the ['Tasks Service'](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/tasks) page. The code autocompleted and saved fine. However when I ran the script I got the 'Access not configured' message. I went to the developers console and the Tasks API appears to be OFF. I do not seem to be able to turn it ON. Do I have to have an OAuth2 API key as well?

I apologise for having to ask for help as the documentation is good but I am confused as to what to do now.

Michael

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

I re-read the documentation to do with enabling an API. I upgraded my script to use the new authorisation flow and then it created a new project ID in the developers console. I was able to turn on the Tasks API and the script is working.

Sorry for the trouble.

Michael

Comment: no trouble, always good to know...(when possible pls mark as answered)